# change object Structure based condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, json

I have an object look like below,

I am trying to reform the object structure based on parent and child relationship.

```
var b = [];
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
if(a[i].parent == null){
const children = a.filter(x => a[i].parent == null && a[i].id == x.parent);
b.push({'name':a[i].name,'type':'grandparent','children':children})
}

}
```

I archived grandparent and child but stuck in sub-children.

Comment: `I have a JSON` - no, you have a javascript object ... JSON never has `var x =` ... jSON is a string representation of an object ... so, you have no JSON at all ... just a plain ol' javascript object ... `I am trying to reform the JSON structure based on parent and child relationship.` - please show actual expected output, not some obscure representation that only you can possibly understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` method and create recursive function for this.

```js
var a = [{"id":0,"name":"Node 0","thumbnail":{"description":"Random Picture","href":""},"parent":null},{"id":1,"name":"Node 1","thumbnail":{"description":"Another Random Picture","href":""},"parent":0},{"id":2,"name":"Node 2","thumbnail":{"description":"A Picture Is Random","href":""},"parent":null},{"id":3,"name":"Node 3","thumbnail":{"description":"Picture, Random","href":""},"parent":1}]

function nested(arr, parentId) {
  return arr.reduce(function(r, e) {
    if (e.parent == parentId) {
      const children = nested(arr, e.id);
      const clone = Object.assign({}, e);
      if (children.length) clone.children = children
      r.push(clone)
    }
    return r;
  }, [])
}

const result = nested(a);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Note that clone is a shallow copy.